# Ajax and Json Search

Tags: javascript, ajax

We found this code online and we are trying to make it work with our project but need help with one small part...

```
    function ajsearch () {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("search", document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append("ajax", 1);
      fetch("2-search.php", { method:"POST", body:data })
      .then(res => res.json()).then((results) => {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
        if (results.length > 0) {
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";
          for (let res of results) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
            line.innerHTML = `<a href='<?= $baseurl ?>/listings/${res["state"]}/${res["slug"]}'>${res["city_name"]}, ${res["state_name"]}</a>`;
           wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }
        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No city or town found request it be added by using our <a href='<?= $baseurl ?>/contact'><strong>contact form</strong></a>"; }
      });
      return false;
    }
```

Now the problem is we need this

```
${res["state"]}
```

To be all lower case and add a hyphon - where there is a space so it looks like this new-york...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: replace java tag with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function in order to replace spaces with `-`, so you can try

`{res["state"]}.split(' ').join('-')`

and can use the [toLowerCase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) to basically make your string lowercase, so it should be

`${res["state"]}.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it didnt work

Comment: line.innerHTML = `<a href='<?= $baseurl ?>/listings/${res["state"]}.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()/${res["slug"]}'>${res["city_name"]}, ${res["state_name"]}</a>`;

Comment: source code shows the following New York.(split...etc

Comment: Any other suggections

Comment: Please provide a type and output of `res["state"]`. Then, it might be much easier to find why it does not work because it should.

Comment: what do you mean  an output of res["state"] above is my full output of the script  sorry newbie here

Comment: just `console.log(res["state"]`

Comment: Ok where do I add this to see what its outputting

Answer (score 0):

We got it we just modified your original code to the following

Please try

```
${res["state"].split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()}
```

instead of this

```
${res["state"]}.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()
```

Comment: It's the same code.

Comment: it is but the placement is different its inside the }

Comment: I did notice that it sometimes adds a hyphen to the beginning instead of between so it looks like this -new-york instead of this new-york is there a way to fix this...

Comment: never mine I figured it out Mysql row had a leading space in front of the value all fixed now...